AppAnvil error -- No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
Im trying install a https://github.com/jack-ullery/AppAnvil
What's wrong is that I can't install AppAnvil even though I have a package installed, the path needs to be corrected. Installed sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev and sudo apt-get install libglibmm-2.4-dev
enter image description here
[enter image description here]
(https://i.sstatic.net/zO7NXqn5.jpg)
`
